# Qual seria uma tradução adequada para "cringe"?

Tags: tradução-inglês, tradução

Eu sei que eu poderia traduzir como "vergonhoso" ou "vergonha alheia", mas a palavra "cringe" representaria algo diferente disso. Eu gostaria de um adjetivo que caracterizasse algo como "cringeworthy", ou "causador de vergonha alheia", ou algo do tipo.

Comment: A pergunta fica melhor se incluir exemplos de uso - uma ou duas frases.

Comment: Subscrevo o comentário acima. Vê também [esta discussão no meta](http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/263/pode-se-pedir-tradu%C3%A7%C3%B5es-para-alem%C3%A3o). É sobre tradução do alemão, mas aplica-se a outras línguas. A ideia, aplicando a esta pergunta, é que tu deves explicar claramente o significado de *cringe* ou *cringeworthy*, para então nós tentarmos encontrar uma palavra ou expressão portuguesa que corresponda a isso. Incluir frases exemplo ajuda, até porque como está, *cringe* é verbo, *cringeworthy* é substantivo, fica pouco claro o que tu queres.

Comment: Digo, *cringeworthy* é adjetivo.

Comment: Queimador de filme. Vexação. Presepada. Fiasquento. Estenderete.

Comment: Creio que num futuro não muito distante podemos contar que "cringe" passe também a fazer parte do dicionário português, como tantos outros empréstimos anglo-saxónicos.  De facto, "cringe" tem adquirido um significado muito próprio e difícil de traduzir

Comment: cringe não se usa só em casos de vergonha. cringe é encolher-se (Michaelis por uma vez está certo) de dor, medo, repugnância.

Comment: ou se acanhar. Por favor, para de dizer que não há tradução. Sem entender os usos das palavras, não se pode traduzir.

Comment: Concordo com a Lambie. Acho que quem diz uma palavra ser intraduzível não sabe o que significa ela de verdade, possivelmente nem tendo conhecimento suficiente da própria língua.

Comment: Acho que seria uma montagem bem estranha, como "envergonhadoralheia". Não temos tamanha articulação na língua portuguesa.

Answer (score 6):

Acredito não existir um adjetivo (ao menos de uso comum) equivalente no Português. A expressão mais próxima é, realmente, a "vergonha alheia", com as adaptações que se fizerem necessárias. Ex: "that's so cringeworthy" -> "isso dá tanta vergonha alheia".

Em alguns casos talvez convenha utilizar "constrangedor", mas acredito que na maioria deles esta palavra carrega sentidos adicionais que nem sempre seriam adequados ao contexto.

Comment: cringe is a verb.

Answer (score 4):

- *When I hear about Donald Trump, I cringe.* = Fico constrangido quando ouço falar do Donald Trump. Mais coloquialmente, Fico "de cara" quando ouço falar do Donald Trump.
- *This new movie is cringeworthy* = Esse novo filme é constrangedor.

Comment: "De cara" me parece uma boa opção, mas tenho a impressão que não seja compreendido por todos os falantes de Português no Brasil. me parece algum tipo de regionalismo. Os usuários de Portugal podem comentar como seria compreendido por lá também.

Comment: @James A respeito de "constrangedor", acho que quase toda a gente em portugal perceberia. Quando muito, o que há é confundir _constrangedor_ com _confrangedor_.

Comment: @Artefacto, talvez tenha entendido mal o seu comentário, mas estava falando da expressão "de cara" e não da palavra "constrangedor". Não sei se a expressão "de cara" é compreendida em Portugal. :-)

Comment: -1 por conter caráter político.

Comment: Não se pode usar exemplos referentes a políticos? Essa regra é nova para mim; onde está escrito isso?

Comment: Independente de regras de qualquer lugar; respostas, em qualquer contexto em que se busca a verdade, sobretudo devem ser imparciais e portanto desprovidas de viés ideológico e manifestações (que podem servir de propaganda) do mesmo teor — o que claramente há em sua resposta considerando a data —, pois a ideologia evoca ânimos indesejados e é inimiga da verdade.

Answer (score 4):

Nos livros do Monteiro Lobato a personagem Emília "torce o nariz" para uma coisa ou ideia quando não gosta dela. Creio que seja uma possível tradução para *cringe*.

*Cringeworthy* seria então algo "de se torcer o nariz".

**Editado:** Outra possibilidade dentro do que as pessoas demonstram que a expressão significa (aquela "cara de repugnância", *"yuck"*, ou de maneira geral choque/surpresa diante do inesperado como citou o L. Augusto) seria *(sentir) desgosto* por alguma coisa ou situação.

[image: Cringe face]

Answer (score 3):

Torcer o nariz:discordar de, ser contrário à; "mostrar desagrado"(:priberam.pt).

Ficar de cara:chocar-se com o inesperado; "Surpreender-se(...)perante ao inusitado"(:dicionarioinformal.com.br).

As expressões parecem definir cringe somente em casos específicos-pelo menos na minha região-.
O uso dos termos constrangedor e vergonhoso soa melhor.Não vejo problema em não ter tradução perfeita, "tricky" é outra(algo entre complicado e enganoso).No meu grupo de formandos falávamos:"V.A."-vergonha alheia- quando um aluno se expunha ao ridículo, kkk.

Comment: Eu apenas trocaria a referência ao dicionário informal, que não pega muito bem. De resto +1.

Answer (score 0):

cringe: acanhar

cringe se aplica a vergonha, medo ou repugnância

Priberam:

a·ca·nhar - Conjugar
(a- + canho + -ar)
verbo transitivo e pronominal

1. Causar ou sentir acanhamento (ex.: o discurso acanhou os noivos; entre, por favor, não se acanhe). = CONSTRANGER, ENVERGONHAR, INTIMIDAR, RETRAIR ≠ DESACANHAR
   "acanhamento", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2021, https://dicionario.priberam.org/acanhamento [consultado em 15-05-2021].

worthy of something: digno de algo OU ter valor de

Então acabamos com: digno de acanhamento, constrangimento, envergonhamento
ou os outros:
CONSTRANGER, ENVERGONHAR, INTIMIDAR, RETRAIR ≠ DESACANHAR

Um só exemplo:

- Your statement about the Chinese is cringeworthy.
- A sua declaração sobre os Chineses es digno de acanhamento.

Como cringe tem várias acepções, tudo depende do contexto.

Answer (score -1):

Assim como o sentimento de "saudade" não tem tradução perfeita, e a palavra é usada in natura na lingua inglesa, acredito que se poderia popularizar o uso in natura da palavra cringe, ou então criar um neologismo, como fazemos muito bem. Seria algo como:
Substantivo - crinjor/cringeor;
Verbo - cringear/crinjar;
Adjetivo - cringeoroso/crinjoroso;
ETC...

Answer (score -1):

Pode ser traduzido de varias maneiras. Mas basicamente de refere a uma situação vergonhosa, constrangedora e embaraçosa.

Answer (score -2):

“Piegas” ou “cafona” são termos que servem bem

Answer (score -3):

constrangedor é literalmente a tradução